# Applying an operation to every element of a array of struct that combines multiple fields of the struct in a array of struct

Tags: arrays, matlab, struct, performance

I am using MATLAB and

Say I have an array of structures **edge** with fields edge.start, edge.end, edge.length.

Now I need to apply a function that say adds value in each field of the struct. How can I do it without visiting each element in the array in the following manner.

```
no_of_element = size(edge,2)
adding = [];

for i = 1:no_of_element
    adding = [adding;edge(i).start+edge(i).end+edge(i).length];
end
```

My array edge is very large. It consist of all links in the road network of a country and the loop takes a long time and I have a number of other functions like the adding operation I show here.

Is there a single function like find, arrayfun that can be used for every element of the array and the time taken to execute the code is much less.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you just use:

```
adding = [edge.start] + [edge.end] + [edge.length];
```

?

You may need to transpose afterwards, depending on whether you want `adding` to be a row or column vector.

Answer (score 1):

You can eliminate the loop by using `edge(:)` and surround the field in brackets like `[edge(:).end]` altogether like this:

```
adding_better = [edge(:).start]+ [edge(:).end] + [edge(:).length];
```